# please help in auto-updating value in a jtable in java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable, auto-update

can you give any suggestions on how the jtable will update automatically for every check in a checkbox inside a cell in the jtable without using an "update button" in java? I have a code below that will be used for a payroll example. it calculates the amount by multiplying the value in the 7th and 8th row. the 3rd to 6th rows have checkboxes. the 7th row sums the number of "true" values from 3rd to 6th row. Can you give any suggestions on how to approach this? please help?

```
private void tableTest(){
        int nRow = sampleTable.getRowCount();
        int nCol = sampleTable.getColumnCount();
        int counter = 0;
        System.out.println(nRow);
        System.out.println(nCol);
        Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++){
            for (int j = 3 ; j <= 6 ; j++){
                tableData[i][j] = sampleTable.getValueAt(i,j);
                System.out.println(" " + i + " " + j + " " + tableData[i][j]);
                if(tableData[i][j] != null && tableData[i][j].equals(true)){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
           System.out.println(counter);
           sampleTable.setValueAt(counter,i,7);
           counter = 0;
           Integer a = (Integer) sampleTable.getValueAt(i,7);
           Double d =(Double) sampleTable.getValueAt(i,8);

           Double product = a*d;
           sampleTable.setValueAt(product,i,9);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setValueAt, you need to call the fireTableCellUpdated(row,col) method of your table model.

> public void fireTableCellUpdated(int row,
>                           int column) Notifies all listeners that the value of the cell at [row, column] has been updated. Parameters: row -
>   row of cell which has been updated column - column of cell which has
>   been updated

Please refer [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableCellUpdated%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: The code that invokes the setValueAt(...) method should NOT call the fireTableCellUpdated(...) method. It is the responsibility of the setValueAt(...) method of your custom TableModel to invoke the fireTableCellUpdated(...) method.

Comment: I agree to the comment above. Any standard table model implementation will invoke the fire... method from the serValueAt method. Even though my answer is accepted, I would like to know what table model implementation you are using here?